# Pic with output analog signal

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I want to output a sinusoidal signal ( for example ) from a Pic micro controller .

Is  there any type of Pic micro controllers can output an analog signal (not DAC) and how ?

Comment: Your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, which is about programming. Your question may be more suitable on the [Electronics StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a question about programming to me! You can do it by generating a continuously varying PWM where the PWM's mark/space ratio changes on every time period. You need to have a number (for example 360) sine values multiplied by a figure that gives you integer PWM values from 0-2^Resolution_Of_PWM_Timer. IF you then change the PWM mark/space ration after every one (or more) timer periods, then filter it with an RC network, you'll get a decent sine wave on the output of the filter. You can change its frequency by having fewer steps or more steps, making the timer period greater or less etc. Once you have it basically set up you can play to your heart's content!

Why do you not want to use a DAC though?!

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the PWM module in the controller.
 Create a sine table(array) with required output frequency. Load the sine table values to the PWM as duty cycles and repeat the loop. on the PWM output pin You will be getting a pulse width modulated sine wave, fed to a RC filter to get a smooth sine wave.